# Reflecting IN the (y,z)-plane

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the matrix representing the geometrical transformation $T : \mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}^3$, with respect to the standard basis, where
$T$ reflects each point in the $(y, z)$-plane.

What does reflecting a point '**in**' the $(y,z)$-plane mean?

Comment: It means you take the point $(x,y,z)$ to the point $(-x,y,z)$.

Comment: 'In' just means 'across' if that's more intuitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As GReyes said, your linear application transforms $(x,y,z)$ into $(-x,y,z)$.

The matrix is

\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}